# Посмотреть содержимое заголовочного файла (например, cfloat) в xcode - C++

Tags: c++, xcode

В Visual Studio чтобы посмотреть содержимое заголовочного файла `cfloat`, я нажимал правую клавишу мыши на `#include <cfloat>`. Ну, конкретнее дальше открывал `float.h` и видел, что, например, переменная `DBL_DIG` равна 15, и исходя из комментов, это *decimal digits of precision*.

Как получить аналогичную инфу в xcode? Например, я теперь хочу узнать *decimal digits of precision* не у *double*, а у *float*, как мне это сделать в xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Option+click` - открыть всплывающую документацию по методу/переменной.

`Command+click` - перейти к объявлению метода/переменной.

Comment: Command+click действительно открывает файл, но там не указаны значения переменных. Например, нет значения того же DBL_DIG

Comment: ну тогда не перекладывайте работу гугла на xcode https://www.keolo.com/blog/variable-types/

Comment: Большое спасибо, что сказали про комбинации клавиш. Но меня всё же смущает (может, из-за того что я новичок), что в Visual Studio 2013 cfloat показан с комментами и со значениями переменных, а здесь этот файл такой урезанный. Разве они не должны быть идентичные?

Comment: если вы сделаете на нем command+click то увидите, что CFloat, это alias для Float, а он, в свою очередь, является структурой языка swift. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Float_Structure/index.html И я предположу, что где то там внутри прячется тот cfloat, который вы ищете, но эпл его нам показывать не хочет.